# Jquery CSS Selector Requiring Three Criteria to be Met

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I am trying to write a CSS selector that requires multiple (three criteria) to be met in order to enact an action.

```
$('div[class*="clickout"]')
$('div[class*="preferred"]')
$('div[class*="test"]')
```

Basically I want to ensure that all three conditions are met.

Comment: Have you tried [JQuery multiple attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)?

Comment: @rfausak: What kind of lame titles does the jQuery documentation give to different combinations of selectors? (+1 to your comment.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chain the attribute selectors:

```
$('div[class*="clickout"][class*="preferred"][class*="test"]')
```

---

If you're looking for an element with the three **exact** class names, like

```
<!-- 3 classes: "clickout", "preferred" and "test" -->
<div class="clickout preferred test"></div>
```

rather than with classes with the three words as partial or whole class names, like

```
<!-- 2 classes: "clickout-preferred" and "testing" -->
<div class="clickout-preferred testing"></div>
```

Then you should chain class selectors instead of attribute selectors:

```
$('div.clickout.preferred.test')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div[class*='one'][class*='two'][class*='three']")
```